# Most Comprehensive Chemistry Book(s)?

Tags: books

Although I am now taking a pretty fundamental chemistry course, I am really looking to gain an extremely comprehensive knowledge of the subject, specifically, in inorganic and organic chemistry. I am looking for two texts, keeping in mind that the most important thing is **comprehensiveness** and the most information about the most topics, not ease of readability. I have the time and dedication to do it, but I really don't want to start with a book that doesn't cover everything and I have to fill in the holes as I go or individually seek out topics it misses.

Comment: No matter what the cost like $1000 of dollars?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the inorganic chemistry I recommend Holleman-Wiberg's text, also exists in english. It is reasonably readable and very thick and contains a lot. 
[Holleman-Wiberg's Inorganic Chemistry](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0123526515). If you prefer, the original is in German and updated very often.

For the organic chemistry, besides being thick also very nicely readable,  [Organic Chemistry by Clayden, Greeves and Warren](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0199270295)

Besides that, you would probably need some nice general chemistry book, but I have no good personal experience in this area.

Comment: For Organic Chemistry, definitely "Organic Chemistry by Clayden, Greeves and Warren".

Comment: Sorry to say it (I love the Clayden, I really do) but in terms of comprehensiveness the Clayden would not be my first choice for Organic Chemistry. Here, the [Smith and March](http://www.amazon.com/Marchs-Advanced-Organic-Chemistry-Mechanisms/dp/0470462590/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1409838336&sr=8-1&keywords=Smith+march+organic) is the gold standard.

Comment: @Philipp: of course I fully agree, how could I forget about "Jerry". Needless to say, I think it is not the book you can read cover to cover without reasonable background. That's why Clayden immediately popped in my mind, as the question was stated.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the list some books which i fill it is good and detailed:

1. [IB Chemistry Course Book 2014 edition: Oxford IB Diploma Programme](http://www.amazon.in/Chemistry-Course-Book-2014-Programme/dp/0198392125?tag=googinhydr18418-21)
2. [General Chemistry (Dover Books on Chemistry)](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0486656225)
3. [Comprehensive Chemistry by Dr. N.K. Verma, Prof. S.K. Khanna and Dr. B. Kapila](http://www.amazon.in/Comprehensive-Chemistry-Dr-N-K-Verma/dp/938038694X/ref=sr_1_2?ie=UTF8&qid=1409818775&sr=8-2&keywords=comprehensive+chemistry)